Formula based on selected Bucket columns
I’ve created a report with two buckets: SLA Met and SLA Not Met. However, the report auto-generated an additional column labeled as "-". I’ve highlighted in the attached screenshot.
I'm using a formula to calculate the Average Handle Time (AHT) for the day with the following formula: LiveChatTranscript.ChatDuration:SUM / RowCount. However, I don't want the counts returned under the "-" column to be considered in the AHT calculation. Instead, the formula should be based on the sum of chat duration divided by the sum of SLA Met and SLA Not Met.
I can exclude those counts by applying a filter to the field Waittime. However, I also need to use the counts returned under the "-" column in another formula.
Can anyone advise on how to adjust the formula to exclude the "-" column from the AHT calculation while still being able to use the counts from the "-" column in a different formula?
Thank you!

